# How to make sure a buffer is stored in cache on arm 9

Tags: arm

I have a character buffer which i want to place in Cache ,how to make sure that in memory map the compiler places this in DCache.

Compiler is RVCT 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "cache lockdown", and is supported by most (if not all) ARM9 processors, depending on the cache architecture. [Here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0151c/I27881.html) is a useful page from the ARM920T reference manual, including some example code. You should be able to find information for your specific processor in the table of contents on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of such feature in ARM. There is the `PLD` instruction that is a hint for preloading some data.